# Cancel in app auto renewal subscription android

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscriptions

I am using google in-app billing v-3 to implement auto renewal subscription process of google in my android application.

In my application user can go for different types of subscriptions, like Subs-1 for 30MB of space, Subs-2 for 90MB and so on. Now if, user chooses initially Subs-1 and then upgrades it to Subs-2, as a result now there are two simultaneous subscriptions on user's account.

I want to cancel first subscription, when second is purchased. Is there any method for the same in android code, or do I have to go for server-side implementation of the same [here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions#resource-representations).

Google docs are really confusing, and I didn't find any solution there.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you could use the cancel method, detailed here https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions/cancel#request

All you would need is the subscription_id and token which you got when user purchased the subscription

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, just wanted to confirm can this be done from android application? As the api request need access_token also. So i guess it would be handled by server end. Is there any method that I can cancel it through my application?

Comment: Yes, server side call would be the best way to go forward. Technically, as it is just a HTTP call you can make it from your android app, but as you mentioned that may end up exposing the token which is not desirable

Comment: Thank you Abhishek, was a great help!